# Mysql возвращает null при добавлении картинки

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images
(
  id    int  not null auto_increment primary key,
  image longblob not null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobs
(
  id          int          not null auto_increment primary key,
  name        varchar(255) not null,
  description text,
  salary      int,
  site        int          not null,
  foreign key (site) references images (id)
);

INSERT INTO images VALUES (1, LOAD_FILE('/home/user/hh.png'));
```

Возвращает ошибку:

> [2019-03-01 13:36:45] [23000][1048] Column 'image' cannot be null

БД и картинка находятся на одном и том же компьютере. Права у картинки 777. Картинка меньше 64 кб.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `LOAD_FILE` может вернуть `NULL` [в следующих случаях](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)

> To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you
>   must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the
>   FILE privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less
>   than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable
>   is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be
>   located in that directory.

То есть должны быть:

- права у самого пользователя на вызов таких функций
- файл должен быть указан абсолютным путём на том же самом хосте что и сервер `mysql`
- файл должен иметь достаточно открытые права для чтения
- файл должен быть меньше `max_allowed_packet`
- если настроено `secure_file_priv` - то файл должен располагаться с учётом этой настройки

Проверяйте по порядку, помимо прав файла и частично размера вы не проверили, есть ли у вашего пользователя mysql от имени которого вы выполняете запрос привилегия `FILE`, а так же в каком состоянии настройка `secure_file_priv`.

PS: хранить бинарники в базе вообще идея с недостатками (например, резкий рост размер базы, где ресурсы i/o и памяти и без того есть на что потратить более полезное), обычно файлы хранят отдельно, а в базе только сведения где сами файлы лежат.

Comment: Я смог загрузить картинку в БД, но я могу делать это только в директории /var/lib/mysql-files/

Я менял настройки /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf добавлял туда строку

secure_file_priv = ""
перезапускал сервер, но это не помогло

Можно ли настроить так, чтобы можно было брать файлы из любой директории? Или это запрещено в MySQL?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

В документации написано:
If empty, the variable has no effect. This is not a secure setting. 

Неужели действительно нет никакой возможности это обойти?